# sencha touch jsonp request

Tags: json, sencha-touch, jsonp

I am creating a test application in sencha touch that communicates with some other domain via jsonp request, but i just can't get the response back every time I get a **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :**, my return json is absolutely perfect with no errors at all

also I can't change the remote function in the other domain that always returns me json object no script tag and method execution, is there any way to fix this **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :** in the above scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server needs to return in the HTTP body something like

```
Sencha.json.callback1({example:'data'});
```

where Sencha.json.callback1 is taken from the "callback" query parameter.

Comment: in sencha would that look something like: **params: { callback: "Sencha.json.callback1" }** ?